# DML statements in reader account is not supported, but object creation is supported

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The documentation of Snowflake says as below, which is correct. I could not do an insert, but it allowed me to create a table within a database.

> Users in a reader account can query data that has been shared with the
> reader account, but cannot perform any of the DML tasks that are
> allowed in a full account, such as data loading, insert, update, and
> similar data manipulation operations.

```
use database db1;
use schema db1_schema;
create or replace table t1(col varchar);
```

[image]

But when I tried to insert into the table, it said insert cannot be done in reader accounts. Should not creation of objects be then disallowed in reader accocunts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No - because a reader account is empty until you configure it by creating objects: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-config

Comment: Are you saying, if I create a role and give insert privileges to tables, it can run DML statements, i doubt that. It will not serve its name(reader accounts). my question is if DML statements are not allowed, why it even allows to create an object, for example creating the table

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to? What about it is unclear regarding why the ability to create objects is required in a Reader account?

Comment: I am already aware of that link and read it, but it does not answer my question. Please read my question again. I am asking why should I be given the ability to create an object in a reader account. I was able to create an object(table) in the reader account

Comment: The link explains why you need to be able to create objects in a reader account. If you are explicitly asking why you can create a table object (which has no real purpose) as opposed to a database object (which you obviously need to be able to do in a Reader account) then it is probably because it is easier for Snowflake to allow all CREATE statements and prohibit all INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements rather than maintain rules for each object type that would then need to be enhanced as/when they introduce new object types

Comment: That may be possible; may be it is easier not to mess with the creation which is more of a metadata operation

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation 'https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create#what-is-restricted-allowed-in-a-reader-account'
, create table command is allowed in reader account.

"
The following commands cannot be executed in a reader account:

INSERT

UPDATE

DELETE

MERGE

COPY INTO

CREATE MASKING POLICY

CREATE PIPE

CREATE ROW ACCESS POLICY

CREATE SHARE

CREATE STAGE

SHOW PROCEDURES

**All other operations are allowed.**

"